# Why the order of wildcard results might be different when used from the terminal or from perl?

Tags: shell, wildcards, perl

There's a folder with a bunch of files and a perl scrip that lists them using ls with a wildcard like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("ls -U -1 dir/*");
```

I noticed that if I run exactly the same command from my bash terminal, I'll get the same results but they are in a different order.

Why might this be? Is the wildcard handled differently in both contexts?

Example:

```
mkdir dir
touch dir/a_0 dir/a1_0
```

terminal output:

```
dir/a_0
dir/a1_0
```

perl output:

```
dir/a1_0
dir/a_0
```

Comment: Can you post your output?

Comment: Do you see a difference between `system("locale")` in perl and `locale` in a terminal? `perl`'s `system()` will typically call `/bin/sh`, what shell are you trying that in in the terminal? (note that it's shells that expand wildcards, so it depends on the shell implementation, and for some shells on the locale).

Comment: Shell settings might also vary depending on whether it is started interactively or not.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas there's no difference in locale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl's `system("cmd")` function typically forks a process, and in the child process, runs the system's shell (typically `/bin/sh`) with as arguments, `["sh", "-c", "cmd"]`, to have `sh` parse and execute  that shell command line.

As an optimisation, it may sometimes do without a shell call, if `cmd` doesn't contain any shell meta-characters (like quoting characters or globbing characters or things like `;`, `&&`...) other than space and tab, but here we have shell meta-characters since we have a `*`.

So, that `ls -U -1 dir/*` will be interpreted by the system's shell.

It is the shell that expands `dir/*` to a list of matching files passed to `ls`, so the way it's done depends on the shell.

In a terminal, you typically run your login shell, which is generally not `/bin/sh`. Also (as [noted by peterph](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94412/why-the-order-of-wildcard-results-might-be-different-when-used-from-the-terminal/94414#comment143399_94412)), that shell, since it's run interactively will typically read configuration files like `~/.zshrc` (if the shell is `zsh`) where some settings might affect  how globbing is done.

For instance:

My shell is `zsh`, and I've got a `setopt dotglob` in my `~/.zshrc`, so:

```
$ echo *
.a d é f
```

Without reading the `~/.zshrc`:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo *'
d é f
$ LC_ALL=C zsh -c 'echo *'
d f é
```

You'll notice that `zsh` honours the locale when sorting the list.

```
$ sh -c 'echo *'
d f é
```

`sh` (which in my case is Debian `ash`) doesn't honour the  locale and sorts as if in the C locale.

If you want `perl`'s `system()` to interpret the command line with a particular shell, you can write it:

```
system("zsh", "-c", "cmd");
```

When passed more that one argument, `perl`'s `system()` never implicitly calls a shell, so above, it forks a process in which it runs `/bin/zsh` with `["zsh", "-c", "cmd"]` as arguments.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu, which makes sh default to dash (which is what perl will end up using) but uses bash for the terminal. Indeed, explicitly telling perl to use bash makes both options return the same results. Thanks @StephaneChazelas.